# Getting Value of Selected Dialoginterface Button

Tags: java, android, settext

I'm trying to get the value of the selected button in the Dialog interface and then put the value as the text of a button.

```
public void onClick(View w) {
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, list);

  new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
  .setTitle("Year of Birth")
  .setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        spinner_button.setText(which);
      dialog.dismiss();
    }
  }).create().show();

}
```

I'm however unable to properly get the value and set it as the text of the button.

Update:
got the answer

```
public void onClick(View w) {
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, list);

      new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
      .setTitle("Year of Birth")
      .setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            String dateResult = list.get(which);
            spinner_button.setText(dateResult);
          dialog.dismiss();
        }
      }).create().show();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by getting the value of the button ?

I think you have to instanciate each button like this :

```
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonId)
```

and after that use OnClickListener and see if this button was click write on it his number.

Say if it helps. If not, explain what you want.

Comment: Get the value of the button clicked in the dialog interface and then set that value as the text of the button "spinner_button".

Comment: but I don't undersant what you call the "value" of the button. The number ? the text ?

Comment: where do you instanciate (or something simular) your buttons ?

Comment: The dialoginterface is fed by this

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, list);

I want to get the value(be it number or text doesnt matter) of the selected item in the dialog interface and replace the text of another button with it.

Comment: if it's the number of the list you have to do : list[which].toString(); and this is the text you want to put in you spinner_button.setText

Comment: I get the position of the clicked item. But I cant figure out how to get the actual value and set it as the text of another button.

Comment: if it is the position, have you try to read the actual value in the "list" ? And you can put it using : `spinner_button.setText(value);`